# MongoNetwork ECONNREFUSED when renaming service and database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, docker

I have a problem starting mongodb with Docker. I have some code which i want to reuse for different purpose. After i made a copy of that code everything worked just fine but after renaming the service, database and building everything again with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build
```

and running with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

mongodb won't start and i get the ECONNREFUSED error. I tried to remove all the services and containers with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml rm
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

but nothing seems to help. I also tried to discard all the changes i made (to the point where it worked) but it still doesn't work. I am quite new to programming itself and have no idea what is happening. What am i missing?

Also including my `config.js`, `.env` and `docker-compose.dev.yml` files.

Config.js

```
const config = {
  http: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 9000,
  },

  mongo: {
    host: process.env.MONGO_HOST || 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    dbName: process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME || 'myresume',
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
MONGO_HOST=mongodb://db:27017
MONGO_DB_NAME=myresume
PORT=9001
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  myresume-service:
    build: .
    container_name: myresume-service
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    links:
      - mongo-db
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/myresume-service/src
  mongo-db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - myresume-service-mongodata:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "myresume"

volumes:
  myresume-service-mongodata:
```

Comment: Should you be connecting to `mongodb://db:27017` or `mongodb://localhost:27017`? If the latter then maybe try and delete `MONGO_HOST` from your `.env` file

Comment: @DSCH Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure but I think that your service needs the env var
`MONGO_HOST=mongodb://mongo-db:27017` instead of the one that you have. The two services are only visible to each other that way. I believe you also need a network to connect the two of them.

something like this:

```
version: "3"

networks:
    my-network:
        external: true

services:
  myresume-service:
    build: .
    container_name: myresume-service
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    links:
      - mongo-db
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/myresume-service/src
    networks:
      -  my-network
  mongo-db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - myresume-service-mongodata:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "myresume"
    networks:
      -  my-network

volumes:
  myresume-service-mongodata:
```

you probably need to create the network using the command:
`docker network create my-network`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't seem to work.  The biggest question for me is why it worked before. Literally the only thing i did was to change the name of the service and database...

Comment: was the mongo service called ``db``?, it seems to me that that is the problem. The name of a service is how it is visible to the other services in docker-compose. localhost never works because it refers to the same docker container (unless you want to refer to the same service)

Comment: yes it was, it seems to work now but i changed other things than this one while trying to fix it. What still confuses me is that i deleted all the containers and services that i had before in docker, so there shouldn't really be some kind of conflict..? Anyway thank you for your time and answer, i am closing this for now.